# How can I create a cell array with the content of a component of a structure? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the structure "sFiles" that contains a component called "FileName" I want to put the information of sFiles.FileName inside a cell aray called "yourcell".

I have this code:

```
for i=1:1:length(sFiles)

yourcell={sFiles(i).FileName};

end
```

Does anybody know why it's not working?

Thanks

Comment: We need more information, please provide an example input and the desired output for this example.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are overwriting the value of `yourcell` with a separate cell array each time.

Refer to the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-cells-to-a-cell-array.html) for info on how to add info to a cell array.

> Create a 1-by-3 cell array.

`C = {1, 2, 3}`

`C=1×3 cell array {[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}`

> Assign data to a cell outside the current dimensions. MATLAB® expands the cell array to a rectangle that includes the specified subscripts. Any intervening cells contain empty arrays.

`C{4,4} = 44`

`C=4×4 cell array`

```
{[       1]}    {[       2]}    {[       3]}    {0x0 double}

{0x0 double}    {0x0 double}    {0x0 double}    {0x0 double}

{0x0 double}    {0x0 double}    {0x0 double}    {0x0 double}

{0x0 double}    {0x0 double}    {0x0 double}    {[      44]}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do the following (without a for loop):

```
yourcell={sFiles.FileName};
```